# getSchedule return no odata.nextlink

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

sorry I'm new to MS Graph. I'm working on a app to extract meeting history data for past hour/day/week/month for my company. first I start with getSchedule endpoint. I found I never see odata.nextlink in the response, even I make the large time range, 60 days. still no odata.nextlink.
my quesion is:

I don't have enough meeting? if yes, how many meetings will cause odata.nextlink?

is it possible, getSchedule will never return odata.nextlink?

I also try add top=2, (v1.0/me/calendar/getSchedule?$top=2), still no odata.nextlink in the response.

Thanks
Wes

Comment: Odata.Nextlink is provided only when there are more number of records you get as a response. There is a [concept of paging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging) where the api's have their own default number of records per page. Here since you are using getScheduler, it gives you a response of different schedules of users or distributed list or resources you asked in the payload. Top is used when you want data of a HTTP call in a single page. It can accept values between 1 and 999. Please check this [document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#top-parameter)

Comment: Thank you, @Shiva-MSFTIdentity, I got the idea of top. do you know how many meetings will trigger odata.nextlink? I cannot find it in the doc

Comment: Its not the meeting that trigger the next link, it's the number of user accounts you give in the request body in the "schedules" property for this getScheduler endpoint. Try giving 20 user accounts in schedules and see if you can see next link. if not increase number of accounts and test it. You will get the result.

Comment: Thank you again, @Shiva-MSFTIdentity, I already tested this case. I put 20 user accounts (meeting room accounts), still no odata.nextlink. that's why I'm asking if there is not enough meeting. at the same time, I tried to create a tool to create meeting (create event). now I have problem to make it work, ref: MS Graph create event not work properly with getSchedule, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64285310/ms-graph-create-event-not-work-properly-with-getschedule

Comment: Try with 101, Max this would be the answer. I am not sure about the exact number since I didn't check for that many users. I have seen only 100 per page for /users endpoint so this should be it.

Comment: Thank you again, @shi

Comment: Moving this to Answer. :)-

Answer (score 0):

Odata.Nextlink is provided only when there are more number of records you get as a response. There is a [concept of paging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging) where the api's have their own default number of records per page. Here since you are using getScheduler, it gives you a response of different schedules of users or distributed list or resources you asked in the payload. Top is used when you want data of a HTTP call in a single page. It can accept values between 1 and 999. Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#top-parameter).

Also try with 101 user accounts, Max this would be the answer. I am not sure about the exact number since I didn't check for that many users. I have seen only 100 per page for /users endpoint so this should be it.

Comment: thank you again, @Shiva - MSFT Identity. the docs says, only max 20 accounts allow in schedules. I fixed my create event issue, and created about 2000 meetings in 35 rooms/2 days. getSchedule response did not have odata.nextLink, and not all the meetings returned. is this a bug? I did it in 20 accounts for each call. I will test with all 35 accounts

Comment: hi @Shiva - MSFT Identity, I just tested with all the meeting room accounts I have, total 33 of them. same result, no odata.nextLink in response and not complete data set returned.

Comment: Aaw, thats strange. Can you please share the detailed response/request logs? Unfortunately when i tried the above, it worked for me without any issue. If you believe it's bug then you you can consider filing a support ticket with Microsoft.