# MS Graph create event not work properly with getSchedule

Tags: calendar, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-calendar

sorry I'm new to MS Graph. I'm working on a app to extract meeting history data for past hour/day/week/month for my company. I'm working on a tool to create event. I use [create event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), after I create event, I use getSchedule with schedules as the same meeting room, but nothing found. I can see the meeting in outlook, but does not appear correct. e.g. for the same meeting room, in normal case, it will show the capacity (e.g. 100 people), for the meeting created from API, I cannot find that kind of information.
here is code I used in create event:

```
"location": {
    "displayName": "London-DaVinci"
}
```

here is the displayName, I also tested with email address and alias, none of them works.
what could be go wrong?

Thanks
Wes

Comment: Ok, i tried the following and its working for me:
1) Create new meetingroom
2) Call events Graph API call and made sure the above meeting room is part of that
3) The above will create a new event
4) Now make the getschedule API call for the above timestamp
5) It will return the freebusy info

Just like this:

Request:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/getschedule
(add the payload to get the schedule)

Response:
"value": [
        {
            "scheduleId": "testroombox@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
            "availabilityView": "000111111111111111111111111110000",

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: I found I have to include the meeting room account in attendee, then it works.

Comment: Yes you have to include the room account as part of the payload and it will work as i updated above. Glad that it worked for you @wessleywang. So i will go ahead and convert this as answer, so it can be useful to others as well. You can upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i tried the following and its working for me:

1. Create new meeting room
2. Call events Graph API call and made sure the above meeting room
   is part of that
3. The above will create a new event
4. Now make the getschedule API call for the above timestamp for the meeting room
5. The graph api call will return the freebusy info

Just like this:

```html
Request:

    graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/getschedule (add the payload to
    get the schedule for the meeting room) 

Response: 

"value": [ { "scheduleId":
    "testroombox@contoso.onmicrosoft.com", "availabilityView":
    "000111111111111111111111111110000"
```